# Changing size of Swing JPanel inside of an Eclipse plugin's ViewPart (despite SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable()))

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, runnable, swt-awt

Today, I am working on an Eclipse plugin project, where I am using the standard SWT_AWT bridge in order to plug my Swing components in:

```
public class MyView extends ViewPart {

    public static final String ID = "HelloRCP.view";
    Frame frame;

    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

        Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
        this.frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            private MainPanel swingPanel;

            public void run() {

                this.swingPanel = new MainPanel();
                frame.add(swingPanel);
            }
        });

        this.setResizeListener();

    }
    public void setFocus() {}


    private void setResizeListener() {
        this.frame.addComponentListener(new frameResizeListener(this));
    }

    public Frame getFrame() { return this.frame; } 
}
```

I would like to get the "`frameResizeListener`" to somehow trigger an update of all subsequent Swing components (e.g. JPanels) constructed by the Swing Runnable instance, this upon the ViewPart's size-change, in order to achieve some kind of responsive design.
Somehow then, the underlying JPanels need to get to know about the ViewPart's Frame size...

I have read my fair share of SO Q&As, and only found the answer that "you need to pass a parameter at construction time". But my problem with this is that my usecase happes once the Components in question are already created and living...

The only solution that I see, so far, seems to break Thread-safety, by writing a shared file or property, and then signalling the Runnable to read it once done.

**Can anyone else think of a better option please?**

Thank you very much in advance for your support ! :) :)

Regards,
Peter

Comment: A valid [mre] would help some of us to better understand your code and your problem quickly. Please consider creating and posting one. The link explains exactly what I'm requesting, and how creating one can help both you and us.

Comment: So wait, are you combining SWT with Swing? If so, why?

Comment: A better option is to just use SWT, although you can embed Swing like this it often causes problems with the interaction between the SWT and Swing.

Comment: Hello @HovercraftFullOfEels , thank you for your answer(s).
I'll consider adding the Listener itself a little later for the example to be reproducible.
I am indeed combining both as it's the only way I know to plug Swing onto the SWT context of the ViewPart of the plug-in.
I need Swing for its capability of dealing with multiple layers (typically thanks to the JLayeredPane).

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for your answer. Please see my comment above.